# ERROR 1: libNCSEcw.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-12.04, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to convert some ECW files to GeoTiff with Gdal command lines in Ubuntu 12.04 but ECW was not supported. I followed some instruction for installing the ecw libraries  (http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/ubuntu/2014-May/001090.html) by downloading ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.1.1.bin and everything went smooth up to the point of testing if the extension is working with gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw. It looks like the installation. I get the following error message:

"ERROR 1: libNCSEcw.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I am using gdal v1.10.0. I should also say that when unpacking ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.1.1.bin it provided options for a free desktop-read-only licence or a paid desktop-read-write-only licence. I chose the first but maybe that has to do something with finding and accessing the library?

Anyone else had the same problem before? Your help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,

George

Answer (score 1):

The desktop-read-only option is the good one.

I had the same problem, but I found the solution with luck :

The instructions we followed are written for 32 bits architectures.

In this lign :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1/Desktop_Read-Only/lib/x86/release/libNCSEcw.so /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so
```

I've just replaced the /x86/ folder by /x64/

So a 64 bits libNCSEcw.so was linked in /usr/local/lib.

Then, I've executed next commands :

```
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt-get install libgdal-ecw-src
sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1/Desktop_Read-Only
gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw
```

And voila :

ECW (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.1)

JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.1)

I hope it can help you.

Cheers,

Vincent